# Dell t430 very loud fan noise with pcie ssd

Tags: dell-poweredge, ssd, drac, pci-express, fan

I have new server Dell t430 2 xenon e5-2640v3 64gb ram, 2x 1TB samsung evo 850 ssd and 2x Intel PCIE p3500 400gb ssd. When I installed Intel PCIe ssd server fan ramp up to 80% and is very loud. I tried changing fan profiles to low fan speed and it did not help. Then I tried disabling third party PCIe device fan response, still same speed but iDRAC now shows 4200 rmp instead of 10080 rmp. iDrac logs shows that PCIE ssd was detected normaly and no further action was required. Fan speed goes back to normal only when I uninstall these pcie ssd. Ordered external fan from dell, maybe it will help a little I don't know what to do anymore. Help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior when inserting a third party PCIe card.

This default behavior can be changed as described in [Disabling a Third-Party PCIe Card Cooling Response with Dell PowerEdge Servers](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/extras/m/white_papers/20441533) [broken link].

Relevant excerpts:

```
/admin1-> racadm set  System.ThermalSettings.FanSpeedOffset Off       
/admin1-> racadm set  System.ThermalSettings.ThirdPartyPCIFanResponse 0
```

**Update**: newer generation of Dell PowerEdge Servers do not use this settings as the global behavior has evolved.

Comment: Link no longer exists. Please extract relevant information to your answer next time.

Comment: It might be that the racadm commands are still supported on some Dell server hardware: https://web.archive.org/web/20230713154530/https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/idrac9-lifecycle-controller-v3.3-series/idrac_3.30.30.30_ug/modifying-thermal-settings-using-racadm?guid=guid-af4b39bf-49c3-4f12-a20d-9488b37eeb8f&lang=en-us